# Unable to run Stand alone Java Swing application in different machines

Tags: java, swing, executable-jar, sqljdbc

I have created a Java Swing application in eclipse. And I have packaged the application into Runnable JAR with the help of Eclipse Export functionality. But I am unable to run the JAR in other machines. In my system it is working fine. 
How to make it independent?

The default output folder(i.e for class files) : `Project_Name/bin`

The JRE is present in the `C:/Programfiles/java/jre7`

I have a **sqljdbc** Jar which is placed in the lib folder of the Project in my D drive.

I am using the option **"Package Required libraries into generated JAR"** but still I think the JAR is not able to fine the correct libraries when I am double clicking on teh JAR in a different machine.
Please suggest. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Did you verify if the jar has all the dependent libraries? Also, what's the error that you are getting on other machines?

Comment: `But I am unable to run the JAR in other machines` - what happens exactly? Any error message? Did you try to run it from the command line?

Comment: `sqljdbc.jar` may be made to a specific jdk. What is the jdk on the *other* machines?

Comment: Along with posting the error message you are getting, you can actually open up the JAR file with 7-zip, winrar, etc... to verify if it actually contains all the libs you are expecting it to contain.

Comment: In other machines when I double click the cmd prompt opens and closes abruptly, which should not happen at all. No error message as of now. I will try to see with winzip if all the files are placed or not.

Comment: I am getting UnsupportedClassVersionError in the cmd when I am trying to run the JAR through cmd in other machines

Comment: I am also getting unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting UnsupportedClassVersionError in the cmd when I am trying to run the JAR through cmd in other machines

This means that you are using a lower version of the JRE than the JDK which you used to compile the sources (for example, sources compiled with JDK7 can not be executed by a Java 6 or lower JRE since the class file format and hence the class version has changed).

> I am also getting unsupported major.minor version 51.0

`51.0` is the class file version of JDK 7. Again, this indicates that you try to run your code with Java version 6 or lower.

To verify, check with

```
C:> java -version
```

which java version is actually used by default.

To fix this issue, use an absolute path to the java version you require, like

```
C:> C:\Programfiles\java\jre7\bin\java -jar myapplication.jar
```

Comment: <classpath> <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/> <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Project/lib/sqljdbc4-1.0.jar"/> <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre6"/> <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/> </classpath>

Comment: i have added the classpath for my Jar , I have changed the build path to jre6 but still I am getting the same error. Is it because my system has a higher version of JDK installed?

Comment: but this should not be the issue as I am using eclipse which forces the application to be build in jre6 environment.

Comment: obviously it is not built with Java 6, but with Java 7 - the `unsupported major.minor version 51.0` error indicates this. If you intend to build with Java 6, validate your eclipse workspace and project settings

Comment: Now after pointing to the JRE7 folder my application is opening is all the systems. Thanks you for this wonderful answer.